# boolean型の配列について（ユーザーインターフェース）

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで、質問があります。
boolean型の配列を6個用意して、それぞれのボタンが押されている時（イベント時）は、ある1つの要素だけをtrueにして、それ以外をfalseにするプログラムを書きました。しかし、実行すると、ある通貨を選択して計算した後に、他の通貨を選択しても最初に選択した通貨から変わらないので、falseの命令が効いていない可能性があります。
このように複数のboolean型変数を使う場合、配列はどのように組んで、true,falseを設定すればいいでしょうか？（コメントアウトしている部分は無視でお願いします）

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rate2 extends JFrame {
  int n;
  JMenuBar mbar = new JMenuBar();
  JTextField f0 = new JTextField("");
  JButton b0 = new JButton("実行");
 
  JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Input a number and press the button.");
  JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Foreign Currency→to JPY"); 
  JMenu menu2=new JMenu("JPY to→Foreign Currency");
  JMenuItem item01 = new JMenuItem("USD to JPY");
  JMenuItem item02 = new JMenuItem("CNY to JPY");
  JMenuItem item03= new JMenuItem("Euro to JPY");
  JMenuItem item04 = new JMenuItem("JPY to USD");
  JMenuItem item05 = new JMenuItem("JPY to CNY");
  JMenuItem item06= new JMenuItem("JPY to Euro");

  boolean a=false;
 // boolean b=false;boolean c=false;boolean d;boolean e;boolean f;
  boolean[]t=new boolean[6];
 
  

  public Rate2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setTitle("Please select Currency");
    setLayout(null);
    
    
    add(f0); f0.setBounds(100, 50, 50, 30);
    add(b0);b0.setBounds(150,50,50,30);
    mbar.add(menu1);mbar.add(menu2);setJMenuBar(mbar);
    menu1.add(item01);menu1.add(item02);menu1.add(item03);
    menu2.add(item04);menu2.add(item05);menu2.add(item06);
   
    add(l1);l1.setBounds(50,140,300,100);
    //pack(); 
    setSize(600, 400);
   
   

    item01.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       
       t[0]=true;t[1-5]=false;
       //b=c=d=e=f=false;
       
    }
});

    

    item02.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        
        t[1]=true;t[0]=t[2-5]=false;
        //a=c=d=e=f=false;
        
      }
    });

    item03.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        
        t[2]=true;t[0-1]=t[3-5]=false;
       // a=false;b=!c;d=false;e=false;f=false;
        
      }
    });

    item04.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        
        t[3]=true;t[0-2]=t[4-5]=false;
        //a=false;b=!d;c=false;e=false;f=false;
        
      }
    });

    item05.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        
        
        t[4]=true;t[0-3]=t[5]=false;
        //a=false;b=false;c=false;d=false;f=false;
        
      }
    });

    item06.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        
        t[5]=true;t[0-4]=false;
       // a=false;b=false;c=false;d=false;e=false;
        
      }
    });
    
    b0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(t[0]){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
        
            Dollar d1=new Dollar(n);
           Double d2=d1.Ex();
            l1.setText(n+"USDは"+d2+"円");}
        else if(t[1]){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
            //l1.C1(n);
            Other c1=new Other(n);
            Double c2=c1.Ex2();
            
            l1.setText(n+"人民元は"+c2+"円");}

        else if(t[2]){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
              
              Other c3=new Other(n);
              Double c4=c3.Ex3();
              
              l1.setText(n+"ユーロは"+c4+"円");}

       else if(t[3]){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
                
                Other c4=new Other(n);
                Double c5=c4.Ex4();
                
                l1.setText(n+"円は"+c5+"ドル");}

       else if(t[4]){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
                  
                  Other c5=new Other(n);
                  Double c6=c5.Ex5();
                  
                  l1.setText(n+"円は"+c6+"人民元");}

        else if(t[5]){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());
                  
                    Other c6=new Other(n);
                    Double c7=c6.Ex6();
                    
                    l1.setText(n+"円は"+c7+"ユーロ");}

              
        
        else{return;} 
            
    
        }
      });

      
}


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Rate2().setVisible(true);
    
  }


  
  
  static class Dollar{
   int d=106;
  // int c=15;
   Double dl;Double n;

   public Dollar(Double n){
     this.n=n;

   }

   public Double Ex(){
    return dl=d*n;
   }

  }

  static class Other {
     Double cn;
     int c=15;
     int d=123;
     double e=0.0094;
     double f=0.0667;
     double g=0.0081;
     Double n;
     public Other(Double n){
       this.n=n;
     }
     
     public Double Ex2(){
      return cn=c*n;
      
     }

     public Double Ex3(){
       return cn=d*n;
     }

     public Double Ex4(){
      return cn=e*n;
    }

    public Double Ex5(){
      return cn=f*n;
    }

    public Double Ex6(){
      return cn=g*n;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflowでは、行先頭に空白があると勝手にハイライトされてしまうので、コードを投稿する際は、バッククォートを使って明示的にコードブロックをハイライトするようにしてください。質問する際、本文入力欄上にある「コード」をクリックすると、ヒントが表示されます。また、統合開発環境 (IDE) の機能を使ってコードを整形し、空白位置やインデントを統一しておいたほうが、読みやすくなります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

都度全ての変数に設定し直すのが煩雑、というのであれば、そのような処理を行うメソッドを定義して、そのメソッドを呼び出すようにすれば済みます。

```java
public class Rate2 extends JFrame {
  // ...

  // 対応する配列要素をtrueに、それ以外をfalseにするメソッドを定義
  private void setSelected(int menuNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      t[i] = false;
    }
    t[menuNum] = true;
  }

  public Rate2() {
    // ...

    item01.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {       
       // t[0]=true;t[1-5]=false;
       setSelected(0);
    }
});

    item02.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // t[1]=true;t[0]=t[2-5]=false;
        setSelected(1);
      }
    });

    item03.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // t[2]=true;t[0-1]=t[3-5]=false;
        setSelected(2);
      }
    });

    item04.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // t[3]=true;t[0-2]=t[4-5]=false;
        setSelected(3);
      }
    });

    item05.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // t[4]=true;t[0-3]=t[5]=false;
        setSelected(4);
      }
    });

    item06.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // t[5]=true;t[0-4]=false;
        setSelected(5);
      }
    });

    // ...    
}
```

---

追記

> privateとはどういう意味でしょうか？

[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/68978/2808)に記載したものと同じく、メソッドに対するアクセス修飾子です。

意味としては、これも先の回答に[付記したリンク先](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E82638_01/jjdev/Java-overview.html#GUID-C1756D87-6CAD-4C87-A498-E7C996077D9A)に説明があります:

> public、private、protectedおよびデフォルト・アクセス修飾子では、アプリケーションのフィールドの範囲が定義されます。Java言語仕様(JLS)では、すべてのフィールドに対するデータの可視性規則が定義されます。可視性規則では、これらのフィールド内のデータにどのような場合にアクセスできるかが定義されます。

> フィールドと同様に、メソッドは、public、private、protectedまたはデフォルト・アクセスとして宣言できます。この宣言では、メソッドをコールできる範囲が定義されます。

`private` で修飾されたメソッドは、他のクラスから呼び出すことができない、と理解しておいて基本的には問題ないです(注)。

注:
より正確には、Java言語仕様の[6.6.1. Determining Accessibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)で説明されています。
日本語では、こちらで解説されていました:

- [スーパークラスのprivateフィールドにアクセス - yohhoyの日記](https://yohhoy.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20161216/p1)

Comment: ありがとうございます！privateとはどういう意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

```
t[0]=true;t[1-5]=false;
```

上記のコードで、

```
t[0]=True;
t[1]=False;
t[2]=False;
t[3]=False;
t[4]=False;
t[5]=False;
```

が行われると思っていらっしゃるのでしょうが、javaに、そのような文法はありません。(Pythonのスライスへの代入と混同されていませんか？）

1-5=4ですから、

t[0]=true;t[1-5]=false;

では、

```
t[0]=True;
t[4]=False;
```

が実行されるだけです。

Comment: ええと、`1-5=-4` です。

Answer (score 0):

質問するときは環境に関する情報を詳しく記述しましょう。

- [技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](https://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html)

ひとまずJava 8以降の環境だと仮定します。

[`JMenuItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html)の代わりに[`JCheckBoxMenuItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html)を使い、スーパークラス[`AbstractButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html)で用意されている`setSelected()`メソッドと`isSelected()`メソッドを使えば、`boolean`配列を別に用意する必要はなくなると思います。
（SwingでMVCやMVVMのようなことをしたいのであれば話は別ですが）

さらにこのオブジェクト自体を配列に入れてしまい、ループ処理するようにしたほうが簡潔です。

また、通貨計算では、ほとんどの10進数を正確に表現できない浮動小数点数は使わず、[`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)を使ったほうがよいです。
浮動小数点数で`BigDecimal`を初期化すると誤差が出るので、以下のコード例では`double`型のリテラルは使わず、あえて文字列型のリテラルを使って初期化しています。

ちなみにJavaの[`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)型は`double`型のプリミティブラッパークラスであり、別物です。
（オブジェクト型ではないプリミティブ型`double`をオブジェクトとして扱いたいときにのみ使います）

可読性やメンテナンス性の観点から、変数名やメソッド名には、1, 2文字の短い名前や省略した名前ではなく、ある程度長くて意味のある名前を付けるようにするべきです。1文字の変数名は基本的にforループのカウンターや例外処理のブロックでのみ使うようにします。また、Javaではユーザー定義の型名は大文字で始めますが、メソッド名は小文字で始める慣習となっています。

```
...
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Rate2 extends JFrame {
    private static final int ONE_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT = 3;
    private static final int TWO_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT = ONE_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT * 2;

    private static final String[][] currencyConvertUnitNamePairs = {
        { "USD", "JPY" },
        { "CNY", "JPY" },
        { "EUR", "JPY" },
        { "JPY", "USD" },
        { "JPY", "CNY" },
        { "JPY", "EUR" },
    };

    private static final BigDecimal rateFromUsdToJpy = new BigDecimal("106");
    private static final BigDecimal rateFromCnyToJpy = new BigDecimal("15");
    private static final BigDecimal rateFromEurToJpy = new BigDecimal("123");
    private static final BigDecimal rateFromJpyToUsd = new BigDecimal("0.0094");
    private static final BigDecimal rateFromJpyToCny = new BigDecimal("0.0667");
    private static final BigDecimal rateFromJpyToEur = new BigDecimal("0.0081");

    private static final BigDecimal[] currencyConvertRates = {
        rateFromUsdToJpy,
        rateFromCnyToJpy,
        rateFromEurToJpy,
        rateFromJpyToUsd,
        rateFromJpyToCny,
        rateFromJpyToEur,
    };

    private final JCheckBoxMenuItem[] currencyConvertMenuItems = new JCheckBoxMenuItem[TWO_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT];

    private void selectOneOfCurrencyConvertMenuItems(int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < TWO_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT; ++i) {
            final boolean selected = i == index;
            this.currencyConvertMenuItems[i].setSelected(selected);
        }
    }

    private void displayConvertedCurrencyBasedOnSelectedRate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < TWO_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT; ++i) {
            if (this.currencyConvertMenuItems[i].isSelected()) {
                try {
                    final String inputString = this.f0.getText();
                    final BigDecimal inputValue = new BigDecimal(inputString);
                    final BigDecimal resultValue = inputValue.multiply(currencyConvertRates[i]);
                    final String resultString = resultValue.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).toPlainString();
                    this.l1.setText(inputString + "[" + currencyConvertUnitNamePairs[i][0] + "]"
                        + " = " + resultString + "[" + currencyConvertUnitNamePairs[i][1] + "]");
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    this.l1.setText("Error");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

...

    public Rate2() {
...
        for (int i = 0; i < TWO_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT; ++i) {
            final String label = currencyConvertUnitNamePairs[i][0] + " to " + currencyConvertUnitNamePairs[i][1];
            this.currencyConvertMenuItems[i] = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(label);

            final int index = i;
            this.currencyConvertMenuItems[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    selectOneOfCurrencyConvertMenuItems(index);
                }
            });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ONE_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT; ++i) {
            this.menu1.add(this.currencyConvertMenuItems[i]);
            this.menu2.add(this.currencyConvertMenuItems[i + ONE_WAY_CURRENCY_CONVERT_MENU_ITEM_COUNT]);
        }

        this.b0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                displayConvertedCurrencyBasedOnSelectedRate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```